# Show that every ring with three elements is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Show that every ring with three elements is commutative

I'm unsure how can I proceed with the problem? I found some answers online on $x^3=x$ being commutative, but not sure if this is equivalent to the property I want to show?

Comment: Have you tried proceeding nevertheless?

Comment: Well yes if I have $R$ with addition and multiplication defined then I would want to show that for $a,b \in R$ $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$, but this isn't leading anywhere

Comment: Are your rings unital?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the ring is unital.

Answer (score 3):

In order to even **express** non-commutativity, you need a lot of elements:
You need $a$ and $b$ with $ab\ne ba$. Then of course we must have $a\ne b$, and neither $a$ nor be may be $=0$ (because $0x=x0=0$ for all $x$). Thus our three elements must be $0,a,b$. Moreover, the additive group must be cyclic of order $3$, so we must have $b=-a$. But then $a\cdot(-a)=(-a)\cdot a$.

Answer (score 0):

There's already an answer, but it assumes you are talking about rings with identity.  In fact the statement holds even for rings without identity.

The additive group is cyclic of order $3$.  Let it be generated by $a$, so that the elements of the ring are $0$, $a$, and $a+a$.  Since $0$ commutes with everything, the only possibility for non-commutativity is for $a$ and $a+a$ not to commute.  But, using the distributive laws, $a(a+a)=a\cdot a + a\cdot a=(a+a)a$, so $a$ and $a+a$ commute, so the ring must be commutative.

In fact, it turns out there are only two distinct rings with three elements: The field with $3$ elements, and the ring with three elements all of whose products are $0$.